# Comparing '+' sign assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to compare argument from command line with '+'. If it is equal it should go to add: label. I'm getting three arguments 2 numbers and sign, which I want to compare. Unfornutely it comparing doesn't work.

My code:

```
main:
mov eax,[esp+8]
mov ecx,[eax+4]  //first argument
mov ebx,[eax+8]  //second argument
mov esi,[eax+12] //third argument
mov eax,esi 
cmp eax,'+'
je add
    jmp end

add:
//rest of code
```

Comment: It would be better (faster and smaller code) to use `jne end` to skip over the `add:` block, rather than doing a conditional jump to skip an unconditional jump.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mov esi,[eax+12] //third argument
mov eax,esi 
cmp eax,'+'
```

What you're doing here is comparing a character (which typically is a single byte) with *the 32-bit address of* the string that is the third argument. That's obviously not going to match.

The appropriate comparison would be:

```
mov esi,[eax+12] //third argument
cmp byte [esi],'+'  ; compare the first character of the third argument with '+'
```

Comment: Thank you for response but console shows me: error: ambiguous operand size for 'cmp' when I try to compile

Comment: I figured you were using NASM. If this is GAS with intel syntax you should probably use `byte ptr` instead of `byte`.